# Smallest $j$ for $\binom{n}{j} \geq (n-j)!$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Obviously we have $\binom{n}{j} \geq (n-j)!$ for $j = n$ or $n-1$. What is the smallest $j$ such that this inequality occurs? (or largest $j$ such that $\binom{n}{j} \geq j!$ as pointed out below)

Thanks

Comment: That depends on $n$. First example, take $j = n-2$. Then the question is whether $n (n-1) - 4 \geq 0$ holds, which is true only for $n\ge 3$. Second example, take $j = n-3$. Then the question is whether $n (n-1) (n-2) - 36 \geq 0$ holds, which is true only for $n\ge 5$.

Comment: Note that the question is equivalent to asking for the largest $k$ such that $\binom{n}k\ge k!$.

Comment: Yes, the exact $j$ depends on $n$ (but I don't think there is an easy way to characterize it). I was mainly looking for an estimate of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ask for an approximate solution of $\binom{n}k\ = k!$ where $j = n-k$.

If n and k are large, we may take the normal approximation to the binomial,
$$
\binom{n}k \simeq \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{0.5 \pi n}}\exp \frac{2(k-n/2)^2}{n}
$$
and Stirling's approximation for $k!$,
$$
k! \simeq {\sqrt{2 \pi k}} \Big[\frac{k}{e}\Big]^k
$$
The leading terms are 
$$
n \log 2 + \frac{2(k-n/2)^2}{n} \simeq k \log(k)
$$
which solves for $n$:
$$
n\simeq  \frac{2 k + k \log(k) + k \sqrt{\log(k)^2 + 4 \log(k) - 8 \log 2}}{2\log 2 + 1}
$$
and again, if all numbers are very large,
$$
n \simeq \frac{2 k \log(k)}{2\log 2 + 1}
$$
This should give the general trend.